# What damage can still be done via a reflected XSS through a POST request when cookies are secure and HttpOnly?

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm looking at a web site that has a verified reflected XSS vulnerability in a POST operation.  I'm not sure what kind of exploit an attacker could do here.

- Cookies are all marked as secure and HttpOnly, so malicious JavaScript can't steal them.
- The vulnerability only shows when a POST request is done, not a GET, so the vulnerability couldn't easily be used for phishing by making a URL that starts with a legit domain.
- Using it to hijack the web browser to forward it to a malicious site seems unnecessary you'd have to visit a malicious site that had HTML or JavaScript code to make the browser submit the POST to the website.

What am I missing?  Could this vulnerability still be used for nefarious purposes?

Comment: 3rd bullet.... so that is not that hard to do.... Simple shortened to a site and run the code. No different than clicking a link.

Comment: This is why I don't use cookies. I could never wrap my head around csrf. With a jwt stored in sessionStorage I only have to worry about malicious JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSS is when an attacker can craft a request from outside of your site, GET or POST, and inject his own content into your page.  XSS is possible whenever data from a request is used in a response unescaped.

What can the attacker do once XSS is achieved?  You should consider the answer to be 'anything'.

My go-to example is often this:

The attacker injects code to replace whatever the page is with your login page, and they got it perfect, your user cannot tell the difference.  But the 'fake' login page sends the user's username and password to the attacker, and also logs the user in so they wouldn't even realise it was fake.

Comment: They wouldn't even need to go that far. They could just intercept the request, read it, then let it continue.

Comment: @Darkrum how far?  What request? Eh?

Comment: They wouldn't need to recreate your login page. They could just catch all form requests or XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Darkrum haha, well that's making a lot of assumptions about the page containing the XSS vulnerability, isn't it? It might just be a 'thank you for your order' type dead-end page with nothing of interest to monitor.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have thought of that.  I think of most XSS attacks being passive, but whether the attack recreates the login page or presents the real one and intercepts the form/XMLHttpRequest, they could create a believable login prompt that will show the correct domain (and probably even fool password managers!) and then steal the username and password.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski even a dead end page is enough to reek havoc. Any good attacker has already reverse engineered the api. Injects there code makes all the requests they want and their done.

Comment: @Darkrum, that was my point, so there is no 'intercept the request, read it, let it continue' unless the attacker is so fortunate that it has been made that easy.  Usually the attacker is forcing the page to perform unsolicited behaviour, having done the necessary research to produce a well-crafted attack.